# Generate average time for each unique username in an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object

Suppose I have an array of Object as:

```
const studyTime = [
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8681,
  },
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8867,
  },
  {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 22321,
  },
  {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 1211,
   },
   {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 1213,
   },
   {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1212,
   },
   {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1221,
   },
];
```

I want to generate average reading time for each user as:

```
O/P : {"john":8774,"naresh":8248.3,"Samul:1216.5}
```

For this I tried: From [SO average calculation for each object in array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819819/summarize-array-of-objects-and-calculate-average-value-for-each-unique-object-na)

```
var sum = {};
for(var i = 0; i < studyTime.length; i++) {
    var ele = studyTime[i];
    if (!sum[ele.user]) {
        sum[ele.user] = {};
        sum[ele.user]["sum"] = 0;
        sum[ele.user]["count"] = 0;
    }
    sum[ele.user]["sum"] += ele.readingPeriod;
    sum[ele.user]["count"]++;
}
var result = [];
for (var user in sum) {
    result.push({user: user, readingPeriod: sum[user]["sum"] / sum[user]["count"]});
}
```

but it gives the O/P as:

```
[{user: "john", readingPeriod: 8774},{user: "naresh", readingPeriod: 8248.333333333334},{user: "Samul", readingPeriod: 1216.5}]
```

Is there a way that I can combine two values of each object in an array to form key value like:

```
 {user: "john", readingPeriod: 8774} => {"john":8774}
```

Let me know how can I achieve expected output as :

```
{"john":8774,"naresh":8248.3,"Samul:1216.5}
```

If any other information needed please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could map the `result` array to an array of entries that you create an object with via `Object.fromEntries`, it'd be simpler to do it just starting from the `sum` object:

```js
const studyTime=[{user:"john",readingPeriod:8681},{user:"john",readingPeriod:8867},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:22321},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:1211},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:1213},{user:"Samul",readingPeriod:1212},{user:"Samul",readingPeriod:1221}];

const sum = {};
for (const { user, readingPeriod } of studyTime) {
  sum[user] ??= { count: 0, sum: 0 };
  sum[user].count++;
  sum[user].sum += readingPeriod;
}
const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(sum).map(([user, { count, sum }]) => [
    user, // key in new object
    (sum / count).toFixed(1) // value in new object
  ])
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer..but I'm not able to understand what exactly is going on..

Answer (score 1):

We can also achieve this using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const studyTime = [{user:"john",readingPeriod:8681},{user:"john",readingPeriod:8867},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:22321},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:1211},{user:"naresh",readingPeriod:1213},{user:"Samul",readingPeriod:1212},{user:"Samul",readingPeriod:1221}];

const findAvgTimes = (data) => {
//Reduce the input data and convert an object 
//with key as each user's name and the value
//is the entire object along with the count
  const formattedData = data.reduce((res, obj) => {
    let key = obj.user;
    //if the user data is already is available in the 
    //result object, then add the `readingPeriod` of res
    //with the current object and also increment the count
    if(res[key]) {
      res[key] = {
        ...res[key],
        readingPeriod: res[key].readingPeriod + obj.readingPeriod,
        count: res[key].count + 1
      }
    } 
    //if the user data is not available, then add the 
    //object and add count as 1
    else {
      res[key] = {...obj, count: 1}
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
  //console.log("formattedData: ", formattedData);
  
  //Again use the reduce and then calculate the avg
  const avgs = Object.values(formattedData).reduce((res, obj) => {
     return {...res, ...{[obj.user]: obj.readingPeriod/obj.count} };
  }, {});
  return avgs;
}

console.log("final output: ",findAvgTimes(studyTime))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 3 little steps:

1. create an array of unique usernames used in studyTime
2. extract the average studytime for each username from studyTime in a function
3. map each username in the array into the objects you want

```js
const studyTime = [
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8681,
  },
  {
    user: "john",
    readingPeriod: 8867,
  },
  {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 22321,
  },
  {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 1211,
   },
   {
    user: "naresh",
    readingPeriod: 1213,
   },
   {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1212,
   },
   {
    user: "Samul",
    readingPeriod: 1221,
   },
];

  function calculate_average_study_time(username) {
    const study_times = studyTime.filter( study_time => study_time.user === username );
    const total = study_times.reduce( (acc, study_time) => study_time.readingPeriod+acc, 0);
    return total / study_times.length;
  }

// extract users from array into an array of users with only their names
const usernames = studyTime.reduce( (acc, current) => {
  if( acc.includes( current.user ) === false )
    acc.push( current.user );
  return acc;
}, [] );

// transform usernames into the final object with the averages
const result = usernames.map( username => {
  let object = {};
  object[username] = calculate_average_study_time( username );
  return object;
});

console.log(result)
```